# Can I get a bytes object of length 1 from another bytes object, without slicing?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, byte

Is this the only way to get a byte of binary data?

```
index = 40
data = afile.read()
byte = data[index:index+1] # <- here
```

If I use `byte = data[index]` it throws an error:

```
TypeError: 'int' does not support the buffer interface
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `bytes` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes):

> Since bytes objects are sequences of integers (akin to a tuple), for a bytes object *b*, `b[0]` will be an integer, while `b[0:1]` will be a bytes object of length 1. (This contrasts with text strings, where both indexing and slicing will produce a string of length 1).

So `byte = data[index]` assigns an integer value to `byte` - which as your error message points out, does not support the buffer interface.

You *could*, instead of `byte = data[index:index+1]`, write this:

```
byte = bytes([data[index]])
```

... relying on the fact that the `bytes` constructor, if passed a sequence (note the brackets around `data[index]`), will use it to create a `bytes` object  - but that's not really any more readable, and is significantly slower (by a factor of six on my machine with Python 3.4).